# Summarizing results of random function in Python

Tags: python, list, function, loops, random

Sorry if this has already been asked, I searched but didn't find anything.

I'm having some fun with odds, making a function that uses a list and random weighted results to simulate a race. I was wondering how I would summarize the results of x amount of races.

my code looks like this:

```
cars= ["Favorite", "Second", "Third", "Forth", "Fifth", "Sixth", "Seventh", "Eigth"]
def Race():
    for i in range(100):
        Winner = random.choices(Cars, weights=(33, 28.57, 14.285, 10, 8.33, 6.66, 4, 1.9), k=1)
        print(Winner[0])
Race()
```

In this example, we have eight cars that are racing 100 times.

this prints a list of all of of the winners from each race. How would I get it to summarize how many times each outcome has resulted instead of getting a large list? For example, something like "Favorite won x times!", "Second won x times!", and so on.  I tried using for statements but had no success.

Edit - I was able to clean up my function with help from Ruli and Ashley below. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Add all the winners to a large list and then count how many times you find each element of the list? Or create a dictionary and increment the key belonging to the winner of each race? Lots of ways to do this. Your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow because it needs to ask about _a specific issue you are facing_ after you have _made an attempt_ at writing the code. Remember to include a [mre] that replicates your issue. Please also take the [tour] and read [ask]. It looks like you will find more use out of a thorough tutorial. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: You guys must have misread, because I did make an attempt at writing the code using "for" statements. I was not asking people how to solve my problem without making an attempt. As stated, I attempted. As stated in original post I am very new to this. Even when looking myself using sites like w3schools I can't always find what I need. I figured it was a specific question (I got a specific answer from Ruli..) but apparently this site isn't tolerant of non-code wizards. Any chance you can point me to a different resource with users who are more patient/tolerant of new users? Thanks

Comment: @PoloKing this website is moderated by community, this means by all of us, I did not understand all of the downvotes, your question was clear, I only edited out the parts that are not necessary in questions, we usually dont care about who is asking and what are their coding experiences. Other users however could make different assumptions and vote to close this because this was easy to find in docs/other questions, and one downvote often leads to "waterfall efect". That is however not a reason to abandon SO, you can still get great help here, but make sure to post quality pots :)

Comment: You're right, sorry for my over reaction! I didn't know it was fully community moderated, either. that makes sense. Thank you for all your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why wont you avoid using loop and rather don't do it directly setting k parameter:

```
Winners = random.choices(Cars, weights=(33, 28.57, 14.285, 10, 8.33, 6.66, 4, 1.9), k=100)
print(Winners.count("yourDesiredCar"))
```

If you want all counts you can do with following

```
from collections import Counter
print(Counter(Winners))
```

which outputs something like:

```
Counter({'Second': 31, 'Favorite': 27, 'Third': 13, 'Fifth': 10, 'Forth': 9, 'Sixth': 7, 'Eigth': 2, 'Seventh': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a separate dictionary for results, and each time the winner has 1 added to the value, such as this:

```py
import random
cars= ["Favorite", "Second", "Third", "Forth", "Fifth", "Sixth", "Seventh", "Eigth"]
results = {"Favorite" : 0, "Second": 0, "Third": 0, "Forth": 0, "Fifth": 0, "Sixth": 0, "Seventh": 0, "Eigth": 0}
def Race():
    for i in range(100):
        Winner = random.choices(cars, weights=(33, 28.57, 14.285, 10, 8.33, 6.66, 4, 1.9), k=1)
        results[Winner[0]] += 1
        print(Winner[0])

Race()
print(results)
```

Gives me on output:

`{'Favorite': 28, 'Second': 23, 'Third': 13, 'Forth': 10, 'Fifth': 9, 'Sixth': 15, 'Seventh': 1, 'Eigth': 1}`